# Mocking service calls that return observables in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have been trying to mock some service calls that return observables in my Angular app, but i simply can't create a valid observable that will trigger calls like `catch()` or `map()` in my code. For example:

My service:

```
create(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .post('/api/stuff', { id: 123 })
    .catch(this.handleError)
    .map(this.extractData);
}
```

My spec:

```
let authHttpMock = mock(AuthHttp);
when(authHttpMock.post('/api/stuff', { id: 123 })).thenReturn(Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.error(new Error('500!'));
}));

const myService = new MyService(instance(authHttpMock));
myService.create({ id: 123 }).subscribe(
    result => {
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    }
);
```

The coverage analysis tells me that the `handleError` method has never been executed. On the case of a successful observable, it also doesn't go through the `extractData` method.

Where is that observable going to? How can i return a proper observable in order to test such calls?

Comment: Is there a subscription to the observable? An observable will not execute until there is a subscription.

Comment: There is not. Should i subscribe on the test itself?

Comment: I've added a subscribe call to the `create` call on my spec, but nothing changed.

Comment: I even added a expect(result).toBeTruthy() on it, but nothing. Then i tried a expect(result).toBeUndefined(). Nothing.

Comment: Vinny, could you tell how you run your tests and what mocking library do you use? From the syntax it looks like `jasmine-mocks` but I failed to run it in the browser-based Karma tests.

Comment: I'm using the default from angular-cli, which is Jasmine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your test code I believe you need to have this code:

```
AuthHttp.post('/api/stuff', {id : 123 }).subscribe(data => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mockData first so that service can make use of it.There is 2 files below. Put your component and service name in place of COMPONENT_NAME & SERVICE_NAME respectively.

Spec File ts

```
describe('WalletComponent', () => {
  let component: WalletManagementComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WalletManagementComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [COMPONENT_NAME],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        {provide: SERVICE_NAME, useClass: serviceMockData}      
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(COMPONENT_NAME);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Should create WalletComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

 });
```

You need to create directory called testHelper(or any name) in root directory

serviceMockData ts

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

const result = {
  data: [
    {id: 0, name: 'Temp Data 1'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Temp Data 2'},
  ]
}; 

export class serviceMockData {
  constructor() {
  }

  getWalletAudits() {
    return Observable.of(result).map(res => res);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you subscribe to the error handler? E.g. in your spec:

```
const myService = new MyService(instance(authHttpMock));
myService.create({ id: 123 }).subscribe(
  result => {
    throw new Error('Not supposed to be here.')
  },
  err => expect(err).toBeDefined(),
);
```

(Although I don't think this should be the case).

This is how I mock the failed backend calls:

```
// first, I provide mock http in TestBed.configure...
...
providers:
  {
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => new Http(backend, options),
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
  },
  ... // other providers, like your mockAuthHttp
]


// than in the test, I tell the mockBackend to fail.
// including other stuff here to, just to show a few more things that can be done

it('should handle errors if backend doesn\'t like us', async(() => {
  let service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  let mockBackend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe((c: any) => {
    if (c.request.url.indexOf('/api/stuff') !== -1) {
      // you can check stuff here, like c.request.method or c.request._body
      const err: ResponseError = new ResponseError('Stuff not good.');
      err.status = 404;
      return c.mockError(err);
    }
    throw new Error('Wrong url called.');
  });

  myService.create('whatever').subscribe((r: any) => {
    throw new Error('Should not have been a success.');
  },
  (err: any) => {
    expect(err.message).toEqual('Stuff not good.');
  });
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

First would be, in your service method, use the following:

```
create(id:number):Obserable<any> {
  let url:string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/stuff';
  let data:any = {
    id: id
  };

  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data))
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    .catch((error:any) => this.handleError(error))
}
```

The second method would be, call use the service as follows:

```
create(id:number):Obserable<any> {
  let url:string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/stuff';
  let data:any = {
    id: id
  };

  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data))
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
```

And when you call the service method, use this:

```
this._service.create(123)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
    //do whatever with success
  },
  (error:any) => {
    this.handleError(error)
  });
```

The method you are using to extract data, `this.extractData()`, can be called instead of `res.json()` inside the service, but overall it's the same result.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did you test your code? Because it gives the same error as my attempt. The code is never executed by the test suite.